# DynamoDB query by 3 fields

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Hi I am struggling to construct my schema with three search fields.
So the two main queries I will use is:

`Get all files from a user within a specific folder ordered by date.`

`Get all files from a user ordered by date.`

Maybe there will be a additional query where I want:

`All files from a user within a folder orderd by date and itemType == X`

`All files from a user orderd by date and itemType == X`

So as of that the userID has to be the primaryKey.

But what should I use as my sortKey?. I tried to use a composite sortKey like: `FOLDER${folderID}#FILE{itemID}#TIME{$timestamp}` As I don't know the `itemID` I can't use the beginsWith expression right ?

What I could do is filter by `beginsWith: folderID` but then descending sort by date would not work.

Or should I move away from dynamoDB to a relationalDB with those query requirements in mind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DynamoDB data modeling can be tough at first, but it sounds like you're off to a good start!

When you find yourself requiring an ID and sorting by time, you should know about [KSUIDs](https://golang.cafe/ksuid). KSUID's are unique IDs that can be lexicographically sorted by time.  That means that you can sort KSUIDs and they will order by creation time.  This is super useful in DynamoDB.  Let's check out an example.

When modeling the one-to-many relationship between Users and Folders, you might do something like this:

[image]

In this example, User with ID 1 has three folders with IDs 1, 2, and 3.  But how do we sort by time?  Let's see what this same table looks like with KSUIDs for the Folder ID.

[image]

In this example, I replaced the plain ol' ID with a KSUID.  Not only does this give me a unique identifier, but it also ensures my Folder items are sorted by creation date.  Pretty neat!

There are several solutions to filtering by `itemType`, but I'd probably start with a global secondary index with a partition key of `USER#user_id#itemType` and `FOLDER#folder_id` as the sort key.  Your base table would then look like this

[image]

and your index would look like this

[image]

This index allows you to fetch all items or a specific folder for a given user and itemType.

These examples might not perfectly match your access patterns, but I hope they can get your data modeling process un-stuck!  I don't see any reason why your access patterns can't be implemented in DynamoDB.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for the excellent explanation it helped me a lot. In your example you searched by the creation date of those folders but actually I`d like to search for items in that folder by date. **And that's still possible with your example** by using a composite sort key with the a KSUID as item id. What I can't do is ```get all items from one user sorted by date regardless in what folder that item is in.``` how would I go about that?

Comment: Glad to hear I pointed you in the right direction!  I'm not sure I understand your remaining access pattern.  You could perform a `query` on the base table, specifying the PK only, which will return all items.  Since all FOLDER IDs are KSUIDs, they will be sorted by date.  Are there items other than FOLDERs that you want to fetch?

Comment: Exactly there are items within each folder. I don't want to sort the folders. What I am trying to achieve is to fetch each item (a reference to a file for example) ordered by *item creation date* within a specific folder. I could achieve that by using a sortKey like: ```#FOLDER${ID}#FILE{KSUID}```. With that I can say: get me all files(ordered by date) within a folder from a specific user. What do I have to do to search for each file sorted by date from a specific user. I probably have to use another GSI right?

Comment: Yes, I think creating another index makes sense.  Keep in mind that you could also model FOLDERS and FILES in their own partitions, which may unlock some additional access patterns.

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure about using dynamoDB you should analyze access patterns to this table in advance and chose part `key, sort key` based on the most frequent pattern. For other patterns, you should add GSI for each pattern. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html

Usually, if it is about unknown patterns RDBMS looks better, or for HighLoad systems NO_SQL for highload workloads and periodic uploading data to something like AWS RedShift.